# sharer.php?u= stopped working for my domain

Tags: php, facebook-sharer

Our software has a video library that lets the users send the video links to facebook.  We're using the very simple sharer.php technique.

In the past couple days, this suddenly stopped working.

Here is the link I'm trying to share.  When I go to it, sometimes I see a blank screen, and other times I see the sharer but with no pre-defined content.

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://RachelHomer1234.nowsender.com/e/vd?NW76AT

(Posting the URL encoded one as well.  Neither one works.)

https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2FRachelHomer1234.nowsender.com%2Fe%2Fvd%3FDQT5XC

I use the same sharing code on other websites of ours, and it's working fine, which suspects me to believe there's perhaps some domain blocking going on?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance,
Rachel

Comment: I believe the sharer has been deprecated for quite some time. May be worth moving to proper Graph API integration for future safety.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the problem is in the case of the domain.  If you change RachelHomer1234 to rachelhomer1234 it seems to work just fine.

There is no documentation to back this up, just my own trial and error.

Comment: For CodeIgnitor I added function name and it is working. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can try thru :

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Frachelhomer1234.nowsender.com%2Fe%2Fvd%3FNW76AT

This tool delete cache, if exists.

Now the link works.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help.  I tried that tool, and then tried the link again, and it's still not working for me.  Any other thoughts?

Comment: Slight correction:  The unencoded link works, but not its urlencoded version: https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2FRachelHomer1234.nowsender.com%2Fe%2Fvd%3FNW76AT  Also, we have thousands of users, each with a unique link.  Is there a way to clear cache for an entire domain?  Thanks again for your help!

Comment: I dont know if it exists , unfortunately.

Write your own script which iterate all over links and open it in that tool.